# Interpolation of CSV Data

Tags: interpolation

I have been doing an interpolation of rainfall data using QGIS and the interpolated data has a line which make the data uneven and the isohyets are being cut at the boundary line of 180 Degrees.
I know that this is due to the dateline passing through Fiji Islands but I need a fix for this so that the isohyets are not cut into two different maps

Attached is a QGIS map:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to reproject your data before you interpolate it - pick one of the projections from the marked question's answers and all will be well

Comment: ok i will try and if al is good than will post the maps

Comment: i needed the isohyets to be smooth and gradual throughout the map but the 180 degrees line makes interpolation of data difficult. It looks like the maps is divided into different section

Comment: what projection did you reproject to?

Comment: ESPG:3832 and also interpolation using this projection is taking too much time

Comment: I can provide a csv file of the data which i am using

Comment: I have added the table of data if an expert is able to help me out